# React Native throwing TypeError: undefined is not an object (Evaluating Object.keys(routeConfigs)

Tags: react-native, stack-navigator

I am relatively new to React Native and have some experience in ReactJS. I have been following the docs and tutorials and cannot seem to find where the issue is within my stackNavigator. I am using expo to simulate the app on my phone.

App.js

```
import "react-native-gesture-handler"
import React from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native'
import Routes from "./Routes"

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Routes />
  )
}
```

Routes.js

```
import React from "react"
import {createStackNavigator} from "react-navigation-stack"
import {NavigationContainer} from "react-navigation"
import Home from "./screens/Home"
import createWorkout from "./screens/createWorkout"

const Stack = createStackNavigator()

export default function Routes(){
    return(
        <NavigationContainer>
            <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home" screenOptions={{gestureEnabled:true}}>
                <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} options={{title: 'Home Screen'}}/>
                <Stack.Screen name="Create Workout" component={createWorkout} options={{title: 'Create Workout'}}/>
            </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    )
}
```

Home.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button } from 'react-native'

export default function Home(props) {
    const {navigation} = props
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Workout Creator &amp; Logger</Text>
      <Button title="Create Workout" onPress={() => navigation.navigate("createWorkout")} />
    </View>
  )
}
```

createWorkout.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native'

export default function createWorkout(props) {
  const {navigation} = props
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Create Workout</Text>
    </View>
  )
}
```

I left out the stylesheets to avoid making the code snippets longer than necessary.

I feel like I'm doing everything according to the docs and the only search that came up with my exact issue was this: https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/7499#event-3068928498 where the case was moved and closed and I can't see the comments or find it.

Comment: Did you try update react-navigation into version 5 ?

Comment: That worked thanks! I didn't realize it was still in alpha and running a regular update wouldn't put that version in.